# In R with clustered data, how would you bootstrap at the cluster level and keep the same observation when clusters are chosen repeatedly?

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I am trying to bootstrap sample in R from a longitudinal dataset with multiple observations per person (i.e. data collected in multiple waves over time). So the data look like this:

```
id     wave   variable
101    1      15
101    2      17
101    3      18
102    1      13
102    2      14
102    3      14
103    1      13
103    2      15
103    3      17
```

What I would like to do is sample at the PERSON level and keep only one observation (wave) per person, randomly chosen, but keep the same observation if/when a person is sampled multiple times. So a bootstrap sample could look like this:

```
id     wave   variable
101    1      15
103    2      15
101    1      15
```

but never like this:

```
id     wave   variable
101    1      15
103    2      15
101    2      17
```

I'm struggling with how to code this at all, much less do it elegantly. Any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We could first sample for each `id` one of its `wave` value and then `inner_join` the original data. Then we bootstrap sample from this 'filtered' list...

Create larger data set to reproduce sampling:

```
set.seed(13)
df <- data.frame(id = rep(101:103, each=9),
                 wave = rep(1:3, times=9),
                 variable = sample(1:20,9*3, TRUE))

head(df)
```

> ```
>    id wave variable
> 1 101    1        4
> 2 101    2        2
> 3 101    3        1
> 4 101    1       19
> 5 101    2       19
> 6 101    3       17
> ```

Solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

  boot_size = 1000

boot <- df %>% 
  inner_join(df %>% 
               group_by(id, ) %>% 
               sample_n(1) %>% 
               select(id, wave)) %>% 
  sample_n(boot_size, replace = TRUE)
```

Test if it worked:

```
  head(boot)
```

> ```
>    id wave variable
> 1 101    2        5
> 2 103    3        4
> 3 102    3       11
> 4 103    3        3
> 5 103    3        3
> 6 101    2        6
> ```

```
table(boot$id, boot$wave)
```

> ```
>       2   3
> 101 323   0
> 102   0 353
> 103   0 324
> ```

Looks good, every `id` has values from only one `wave`

## Edit:

I accidentally posted a working but very inefficient and stupid version of the solution, where my join data.frame selected from all combinations of `id`, `wave` AND `variable`. But we don't need all these combinations at this step. I exchanged that line of code with a less stupid one. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You can get a data frame with one row for each ID chosen at random, then just sample this data frame with replacement:

```r
set.seed(69)
dfs <- split(df, df$id)
dfs <- mapply(function(x, y) x[sample(y,1),], dfs, sapply(dfs, nrow), SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
result <- do.call(rbind, dfs)
result[sample(nrow(result), 9, TRUE), ]
#>        id wave variable
#> 101   101    1       15
#> 103   103    2       15
#> 103.1 103    2       15
#> 103.2 103    2       15
#> 102   102    3       14
#> 101.1 101    1       15
#> 103.3 103    2       15
#> 102.1 102    3       14
#> 102.2 102    3       14
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your example:

```
x = structure(list(id = c(101L, 101L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 
103L, 103L), wave = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), variable = c(15L, 
17L, 18L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 13L, 15L, 17L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

Maybe something like this, if you don't mind dplyr:

```
set.seed(111)
x %>% group_by(id) %>% sample_n(1) %>%  
ungroup() %>% sample_n(n(),replace=TRUE)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id  wave variable
  <int> <int>    <int>
1   103     3       17
2   101     2       17
3   103     3       17
```

In the first line, you group by id, and sample 1. Next you ungroup, so you have only unique ids. Then it's a matter of sampling these rows with replacement.. Hope I got it correct.